# Using PHImageManager, is it possible to request a group of UIImages from a group of PHAssets in one call?

Tags: objective-c, ios8, uiimage, photosframework, phasset

If not, what would be the best way to accomplish this?

Say a user selects several `PHAsset`s in the UI, then taps "Done". I want to organize those images into an array of their corresponding `UIImage`s to cache into the app.

Do I have to call `requestImageForAsset` on every single `PHAsset`, and keep a count of how many have been accomplished, and then collate them into an array at the end? Is there no clean way to say "give me the UIImages for these PHAssets"?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. There is no single call that will accomplish this. You must individually request each PHAsset's image and display them together on your own.